# parse error, Expected T_STRING instead of ""

Tags: php, bitrix

I got

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected "", expected T_STRING
>   in ../services/sect_inc_prev.php on line 2

```
<div style="text-align: right;">
    <? if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die(); ?>
</div>
<div class="f13"></div>
```

what is expected as string and where to find the place where "" is?
I need to know where the problem "empty space". I'm not php programmer at all

I deleted the 2nd line and I have no error now, but I don't know for what it was needed. The error was on friend's page that hosted on Bitrix system

Comment: Ammm, try removing the backslashes in the php line of code.

Comment: why you had backslashes all over?

Comment: I tried without backslashes and same result. btw bitrix or some magic add slashes automaticaly and some time it becomes \\\\\\\\\\ :(

Comment: All answers are incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
<? if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die(); ?>
```

Just remove backslashes... Search a little bit more next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try without slashes:

```
<div style="text-align: right;">
<? if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die(); ?>
</div>
<div class="f13"></div>
```